# nw command linked with nanoc

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nanoc

I'm using OSX and installed NWjs, when I try to run a site using `nw ./`, it gives such an error:

> WARNING: The `watch` command is deprecated. Please consider using `guard-nanoc` instead (see https://github.com/nanoc/guard-nanoc).
>   Error: The current working directory does not seem to be a nanoc site.

I'm a bit confused that I'm running nw, but why is it running ruby? Is that for some reason the nw is linked with nanoc? Should I remove nanoc? If so, what should I do?

I tried `gem uninstall nanoc`, after that, I ran `nw` on terminal, the error is:

> command not found: nanoc

Seems like `nw` is linked with `nanoc`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like I have a command conflict, typing `alias` in command line tells me that `nw='nanoc watch'`, which I don't want that.

so ending up creating an alias called `nwjs` in `/usr/local/bin` and link that to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nw/bin/nw`